# Set System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current in MS Unit Tests (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mstest

I have domain classes that reference System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.Id in my web api.  It uses this value as a correlation Id once the object is serialized and stored in Cosmos.  I have no issue getting this value when making calls into the API.  However if I try to reference this value in my domain unit tests, the System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current is null.  I have tried setting it in my unit test functions but it is still always null in my domain.

```
System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current = new System.Diagnostics.Activity("MyUnitTests");
```

I know System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current is driven from the current HttpContext but there also is no current http context in my domain unit tests.  How can I make this work with my unit tests?

Example:
**Domain Class**

```
public class Company
{  
    public int CompanyId { get; private set; }        
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string CorrelationId { get { return System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.Id; } }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        Company c = new Company();
        Assert.AreNotEqual(string.Empty, c.CorrelationId);
    }
```

This unit test throws a null reference exception because System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current is null.

Comment: This is a design issue around mixing concerns and is a code smell. Current code is tightly coupled to run time concerns that are not present when unit testing in isolation. You'll most likely need to run an integration test where actual requests are made with a valid context.

Comment: We have integration tests on top of our domain unit tests so we are covered there.  To reduce the "code smell", might it be better to inject the correlation Id into our services and then use that in our domain entities instead?

Comment: Assigning the id via a service abstraction would help loosen the coupling to run time concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design issue around mixing concerns and is a possible code smell.

Current code is tightly coupled to run time concerns that are not present when unit testing in isolation.

You'll most likely need to run an integration test where actual requests are made with a valid context.

Assigning the id via a service abstraction would help loosen the coupling to run time concerns.

And remove the need to unit unit test a simple domain POCO used to store run time data.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that using `System.Diagnostics.Activity` in a domain class is a code smell.

But I had a similar issue with my unit test. The tested business-logic code uses `Activity.Current.AddBaggage`:

```
Activity.Current.AddBaggage("CustomerRef","SomeCustomerReference");
```

Because only the logic is tested, no HttpRequest is involved and `Activity.Current` is NULL.

So I extended my unit test with the following base class (example is for XUnit):

```
public class BaseTest : IDisposable
{
    private Activity unitTestActivity;

    protected BaseTest()
    {
        unitTestActivity = new Activity("UnitTest").Start();

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        unitTestActivity.Stop();
    }
}
```